# ASP.NET Website installs/updates

Tags: asp.net

I am looking for some ideas on how to offer a installation package for my ASP.NET website. Some things I need to be able to do is read/write Registry keys, get the database(s) information and test the connection and I must be able to overwrite the existing website without an uninstall and update the web config on new versions. I do not wish to uninstall the website and re-install it. I would like minimum downtime on upgrades. I think I am going to have to implement a custom solution and if this is true how can i include all the output of my web application into my custom solution?

EDIT: I am not installing this on my own system(s). This is for distribution to other clients who will be installing/upgrading the website. It is important that I be able to upgrade to the latest asp.net website without uninstalling. Ideally it would be overwriting the existing site and updating the web.config file.

Answer (score 5):

### Option 1. Create web application installation package

Use **Web Setup Project** for creating a web application installation package (.msi)

[Creating or Adding a Setup Project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19x10e5c(VS.71).aspx) at MSDN

You can create your installation the way it will offer user an **Upgrate option** of your application if it's already installed on his or her machine. That's not a problem.

**Alternatives** to Web Setup Project (all of them can handle upgrade scenarios):

- [Wise Installation Studio](http://www.wise.com/Products/Installations/WiseInstallationStudio.aspx)
- [InstallShield](http://www.acresso.com/products/is/installshield-overview.htm)
- [Nullsoft Scriptable Install System](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/)  - this one is free and open source

### Optoin 2. Deploy web application on the server

You can use **[NAnt](http://nant.sourceforge.net/)** or **[MSBuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wea2sca5.aspx)** or **[IIS Web Deployment Tool](http://www.iis.net/extensions/WebDeploymentTool)** for these tasks automation.

For example with NAnt of MSBuild you could specify tasks like these:

- get project files from source repository
- update .config file and maybe some other files if needed
- compile you web application
- update registry settings on the server
- update database schema on the server
- synchronize files (x-copy) between you build folder to IIS web folder

[Web Deployment Blog](http://blogs.iis.net/msdeploy/)

### Option 3. Distribute your web applications via Web Plafrom Installer.

http://www.microsoft.com/web/

Comment: I appreciate your updates. I am not trying to do a deployment to my own machines though, I currently have a really nice setup for that locally that works great. I need to do something for distributing the website to other users as a software package that they can install.

Comment: Got it, then you should use Web Setup Project and compile your web application into .msi

Comment: I don't think this will allow me to do updates without an uninstall though right? And then they would have to go through the information gathering process again and a new install?

Comment: I am sure you can. It also cans upgrate your previously installed web app as well.

Comment: The only problem with Web Setup Project it's hard to customize it without learning from inside out. Perhaps it will be easier for you to use an alternative like Wise, InstallShield or Nullsoft

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into [Web Deployment Projects](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=0AA30AE8-C73B-4BDD-BB1B-FE697256C459&displaylang=en) or the [IIS Web Deployment Tool](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/346/web-deployment-tool)?

Comment: It looks like this solution only handles IIS 7? Also, I am unable to find any information on how it handles updates.

Comment: "Web Deployment Projects" is not good for deploying website especially when you need to make registry changes etc. on the server.

Comment: The Web Deployment Tool does IIS 6 and 7. What do you mean about updates? A package can contain whatever you want it to.

Comment: @Koistya: If you read http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/11/06/429723.aspx, you'll see that you can use a Web Setup project along with a Web deployment project. Sorry, I thought they had merged the two.

Comment: I keep saying updates but what I really mean is upgrades. I need to upgrade the website without an uninstall and keeping the web.config and registry settings.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can build asp.net application into .msi package and install it. Is that what you are looking for? And then you can build all of your customization into pre-deployment and post-deployment scripts.

Answer (score 0):

I use NAnt and NSIS with some small console apps where they can't easily do some manipulations I require.

Answer (score 0):

Do you tried the new [Microsoft Web Platform Installer (new! 2.0 beta)](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/06/02/microsoft-web-platform-installer.aspx)?

[image: Microsoft Web Platform Installer]